# Function used to represent the Riemann Zeta function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, riemann-zeta

Consider the function $g(z)= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\int^{n+1}_{n}\frac{t-n}{t^{z+1}}dt$.

I want to show that this defines an analytic function for Re(z)>0. Later I will use it to describe the Riemann Zeta function by $\zeta(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}-zg(z)$. I thought about proving that $g$ is holomorphic, for this I have several ways, but I didn't find a good one until now. I thought about using Morera's theorem, just trying to compute the derivative or at least show that the derivative exists. Another approach was to compute the integral and then go on with just the sum, but that does also not work well.
What would be a good way to prove this?

Comment: I believe the answer user @reuns posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3447368 to one of my related questions provides some insight.

Comment: Your formula for $g(z)$ is equivalent to $g(z)=\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{\{t\}}{t^{z+1}}dt=\int\limits_1^\infty\frac{t-\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^{z+1}}dt$ which can be evalulated using the Fourier series for the sawtooth wave function $\{t\}=t-\lfloor t\rfloor=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n t )}{n}$.

Comment: $\int\limits_1^\infty|\frac{t-\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^{z+1}}|dt \le \int\limits_1^\infty\frac{1}{t^{\Re z+1}}dt$ which is convergent for $\Re z >0$ so by general theory the original integral represents an analytic function for $\Re z >0$ (being uniformly convergent in any compact set with $\Re s >0$)

Comment: @Conrad I understand the convergence for Re(z)>0, but what do you mean by uniformly convergent? I know that if a sequence of analytic functions converges uniformly to a function on a compact set, then this function is also analytic. But how can I apply this here?

Comment: An integral is like a sequence of functions - eg take$f_n$ the same integral from $1$ to $n$; then $f_n$ analytic because it's a finite measure integral of analytic functions now and converges uniformly on compacts to $f$

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks a lot